# aggregating and sorting in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, elasticsearch-plugin

Recently I started to use ElasticSearch, I am planning to stick to it for a service I am building.

Basically I have the following types:

- searches
- offers
- prices of the offers

Every search has a set of information plus the SID (search id), every offer has an OID (offer id) plus the SID of the search and a set of prices.

I receive the data asynchronously, to avoid using _update, instead of having an array of prices in the offer and update it, every price is stored in a separated document and contains the search id, the offer id and the price itself.

I would to:

- filter by the SID
- aggregate by the OID
- sort the aggregates by price

How could I do it? Any hint? I am reading the documentation about how to aggregate but I totally have no idea :(

**EDIT:**

Here there is an example dataset

SEARCHES (uuid is the sid)

```
{
    'sid_1': { 'q': 'bread', 'sid': 'sid_1' },
    'sid_2': { 'q': 'milk', 'sid': 'sid_2' },
    'sid_3': { 'q': 'donuts', 'sid': 'sid_3' }
}
```

OFFERS (uuid is the sid#oid)

```
{
    'sid_1#kamut-bread': { 'name': 'kamut bread', 'sid': 'sid_1', 'oid': 'kamut-bread' },
    'sid_1#chocolate-bread': { 'name': 'chocolate bread', 'sid': 'sid_1', 'oid': 'chocolate-bread' },
    'sid_1#plastic-bread': { 'name': 'plastic bread', 'sid': 'sid_1', 'oid': 'plastic-bread' },
    'sid_2#soya-milk': { 'name': 'soya milk', 'sid': 'sid_2', 'oid': 'soya-milk' },
    'sid_2#vaccine-milk': { 'name': 'vaccine milk', 'sid': 'sid_2', 'oid': 'vaccine-milk' },
    'sid_2#milk': { 'name': 'milk', 'sid': 'sid_2', 'oid': 'milk' },
    'sid_3#cream-donuts': { 'name': 'cream donuts', 'sid': 'sid_3', 'oid': 'cream-donuts' },
    'sid_3#chocolate-donuts': { 'name': 'chocolate donuts', 'sid': 'sid_3', 'oid': 'chocolate-donuts' },
    'sid_3#square-donuts': { 'name': 'square donuts', 'sid': 'sid_3', 'oid': 'square-donuts' }
}
```

OFFERS_PRICES (uuid is the sid#oid#partner)

```
{
    'sid_1#kamut-bread#amazon': { 'partner': 'amazon', 'sid': 'sid_1', 'oid': 'kamut-bread', 'price': 10.1, 'fees': { 'mastercard': 1, 'visa': 1, 'paypal': 2, 'wiretransfer': 0 } },
    'sid_1#kamut-bread#store2': { 'partner': 'store2', 'sid': 'sid_1', 'oid': 'kamut-bread', 'price': 11.1, 'fees': { 'mastercard': 1, 'visa': 1, 'paypal': 2, 'wiretransfer': 0 } },
    'sid_1#kamut-bread#store3': { 'partner': 'store3', 'sid': 'sid_1', 'oid': 'kamut-bread', 'price': 10.4, 'fees': { 'mastercard': 1, 'visa': 1, 'paypal': 2, 'wiretransfer': 0 } },
    'sid_1#kamut-bread#store4': { 'partner': 'store4', 'sid': 'sid_1', 'oid': 'kamut-bread', 'price': 10.8, 'fees': { 'mastercard': 1, 'visa': 1, 'paypal': 2, 'wiretransfer': 0 } },
    'sid_1#chocolate-bread#amazon': { 'partner': 'amazon', 'sid': 'sid_1', 'oid': 'chocolate-bread', 'price': 7.1, 'fees': { 'mastercard': 1, 'visa': 1, 'paypal': 2, 'wiretransfer': 0 } },
    'sid_1#chocolate-bread#store2': { 'partner': 'store2', 'sid': 'sid_1', 'oid': 'chocolate-bread', 'price': 7.1, 'fees': { 'mastercard': 1, 'visa': 1, 'paypal': 2, 'wiretransfer': 0 } },
    'sid_1#chocolate-bread#store3': { 'partner': 'store3', 'sid': 'sid_1', 'oid': 'chocolate-bread', 'price': 8.4, 'fees': { 'mastercard': 1, 'visa': 1, 'paypal': 2, 'wiretransfer': 0 } },
    'sid_1#chocolate-bread#store4': { 'partner': 'store4', 'sid': 'sid_1', 'oid': 'chocolate-bread', 'price': 9.8, 'fees': { 'mastercard': 1, 'visa': 1, 'paypal': 2, 'wiretransfer': 0 } },
    'sid_1#plastic-bread#amazon': { 'partner': 'amazon', 'sid': 'sid_1', 'oid': 'plastic-bread', 'price': 70.1, 'fees': { 'mastercard': 1, 'visa': 1, 'paypal': 2, 'wiretransfer': 0 } },
    'sid_1#plastic-bread#store2': { 'partner': 'store2', 'sid': 'sid_1', 'oid': 'plastic-bread', 'price': 75.1, 'fees': { 'mastercard': 1, 'visa': 1, 'paypal': 2, 'wiretransfer': 0 } },
    'sid_1#plastic-bread#store3': { 'partner': 'store3', 'sid': 'sid_1', 'oid': 'plastic-bread', 'price': 88.4, 'fees': { 'mastercard': 1, 'visa': 1, 'paypal': 2, 'wiretransfer': 0 } },
    'sid_1#plastic-bread#store4': { 'partner': 'store4', 'sid': 'sid_1', 'oid': 'plastic-bread', 'price': 97.8, 'fees': { 'mastercard': 1, 'visa': 1, 'paypal': 2, 'wiretransfer': 0 } }
    ...
}
```

For performance reasons the code will not aggregate the data, instead it will return them separately (the search, the offers and the prices of the offers) and the frontend will aggregate them, will would allow me to (almost) stream the data directly from elastic without having to pre-elaborate them.

After extracting the search and the offers, I would like:

- to extract the prices for the SID sid_1
- to group the prices by the OID
- to sort the aggregations by price (or by price + a specific fee, but I can handle this with groovy)

Comment: Could you please extend your question with a more concrete sample on how the data looks like and which kind of queries and aggregations you want to perform? What is the goal you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the existence of the aggregation type scripted_metric and, after playing with it I came up with this query

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}
    },

    "aggs": {
        "offer_prices": {
            "scripted_metric": {
                "init_script" : "_agg[\"offers_prices\"] = [:].withDefault{[:]}",

                "map_script" : "def parent = doc._parent.value; def partner = doc.partner.value; def price = doc.price.value; if (!_agg.offers_prices.containsKey(parent)) { _agg.offers_prices[parent] = [ parent: parent, sid: doc.sid.value, oid: doc.oid.value, bestPrice: Double.MAX_VALUE, bestPartner: null, partners: [:] ]; }; _agg.offers_prices[parent].partners[partner] = [ \"partner\": partner, \"price\": price, \"ccfees\": _source.ccfees ]; if (_agg.offers_prices[parent].bestPrice > price) { _agg.offers_prices[parent].bestPrice = price; _agg.offers_prices[parent].bestPartner = partner; }", 

                "combine_script" : "return _agg.offers_prices;",

                "reduce_script" : "def offers_prices_all = [:]; _aggs.each { offers_prices_per_shard -> offers_prices_per_shard.each { oid, offers_prices -> offers_prices_all[oid] = offers_prices}; }; offers_prices_all = offers_prices_all.sort { a, b -> a.value.bestPrice <=> b.value.bestPrice }; return offers_prices_all;"

            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is not the final version, I have to do some fixes and I have to test the performance but it seems a possible solution:

- the query group the data using _parent
- calculate te bestPrice of the aggregation
- sort the aggregations by the bestPrice

Still todo:

- sort the aggregations by bestPrice + fee
- sort the partners list of the single aggregations by price
- test the performance and the resource consumption

Note:

- I have added the _parent mapping and I am using the _parent property of the document to group the data but it is possible to manually build it concatenating sid and oid
- The script is using the property ccfees but in the example dataset I posted above it is called fees